# How do I get disabling SMTP plaintext authentication to stick on OS X 10.10 Yosemite's Server.app

Tags: postfix, mac-osx, mac-osx-server, smtp-auth, osx-yosemite

I've got an SMTP relay server that I recently replaced with OS X 10.10 Yosemite running Server.app. It is running as an SMTP-only relay allowing only hosts from the LAN to relay out through it. We do this so that all mail from our subnet is correctly sent from a verified host for our domain for Sender Policy Framework (SPF) and such.

Configuring to relay out was pretty easy. Following Apple's documentation for [Disabling Mail services on OS X Server](https://support.apple.com/en-qa/HT203002), I did the following:

```
sudo serveradmin settings mail:global:skip_enable_service_check = yes
sudo serveradmin settings mail:imap:enable_imap = no
sudo serveradmin settings mail:imap:enable_pop = no
sudo serveradmin settings mail:imap:enable_sieve = no
sudo serveradmin stop mail
sudo serveradmin start mail
```

That ensured that only SMTP is running and remains the case after rebooting or restarting the Mail service. Since the SMTP relay server's hostname is subdomain in the domain it's relaying for, I also had to modify `/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/main.cf` to remove `$myhostname` & `$mydomain` from "mydestination", the resulting line is as follows:

```
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

That also worked, Server.app recognized and retains the change (as verified by running `sudo serveradmin settings mail:postfix`). The same holds true for tweaks to the `mynetworks` line to limit which subnets relaying was accepted from.

The problem I'm experiencing is that modifications to the `smtpd_pw_server_security_options` line (specifically, to remove the `LOGIN` & `PLAIN` authentication types) will not stick and revert to the default (which includes the unwanted plaintext auth types) upon starting the Mail service. Apple's documentation on [Apple-specific postfix options in Mac OS X Server](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA2431) imply that skipping the `LOGIN` & `PLAIN` options should be valid.

I have tried:

1. the aforementioned modifications to `smtpd_pw_server_security_options` in `/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/main.cf`
2. As mentioned in the Apple-specific postfix options documentation, running `sudo serveradmin settings mail:postfix:smtpd_use_pw_server = no` (`mail:postfix:smtpd_use_pw_server` seems to be an empty dictionary under Yosemite)
3. Running `sudo serveradmin settings postfix:smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes` (it defaults to 'no' under Yosemite, so I assume Apple just swapped this option's functionality from the above `mail:postfix:smtpd_use_pw_server` option)
4. Using `serveradmin` to delete the `login` & `plain` elements from the `mail:postfix:smtpd_pw_server_security_options` array (e.g. `sudo serveradmin settings mail:postfix:smtpd_pw_server_security_options:_array_index:2 = delete`), but as Charles Edge mentions in his kyrpted blog post about [Removing 'serveradmin settings' Entries in OS X Server](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x-server/removing-serveradmin-settings-entries-in-os-x-server/), that functionality seems to be broken. And, no these settings aren't mirrored in `/Library/Server/Mail/Config/MailServicesOther.plist` or any other .plist, so manually modifying those doesn't appear to be an option.

I have gotten plaintext auth disabled temporarily using Server.app by toggling the plaintext authentication setting from a partially selected checkbox (presumably because IMAP is disabled) to a fully deselected checkbox, but it's inconsistent and doesn't stick after restarting the Mail service.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated, with the exception of advising not to use Server.app on OS X. This is for an all-Apple shop which must dog food Apple's products for reasons which I cannot get into here. Naturally, leaving plaintext auth enabled is also not an option for obvious security & PCI DSS compliance reasons.

Comment: *This is for an all-Apple shop which must dog food Apple's products* like an Apple store ? Anyway as a temporary workaround you can always make a shell script that executes the commands you describe above and make that script run at boot.

Comment: Aside from the initial commands to disable all but SMTP in the Mail service, the others do not actually work. I can sometimes get it to disable plaintext auth via Server.app, but not reliably and so definitely not easily automated. Your comment made me realize that I could certainly write a notifier should the plaintext auth become reenabled, so that's a start, but I'd love a full solution or something easily automated.

Comment: I really interested with your problem and I want to reproduce it in my environment. Unfortunately, I don't have Mac OS resources here. Anyway, can you track the process who revert `main.cf` to the default state? auditctl should be useful

Answer (score 2):

I can--with some futzing--get SMTP plaintext auth disabled via Server.app, though it doesn't stick very well (certainly doesn't survive a reboot or restart of the Mail service, and sometimes even gets lost while poking around in Server.app). I realized that, as a temporary workaround, that I can at least automatically notify if the 'PLAIN' & 'LOGIN' plaintext SMTP auth gets re-enabled.

I whipped up the following quick bash script that does the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 
# smtp_plaintext_auth_check - check to see if plaintext auth is supported by SMTP service and warn if it is
# 
# v0.1   2015-03-12 - Morgan Aldridge <http://serverfault.com/users/13496/morgant>
#                     Initial version.
# 

admin_emails="email@domain.tld"
debug=false

host=$(hostname)
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M)

plaintext_auth_enabled=false

# check via serveradmin to see if plaintext auth is allowed by the SMTP server
if $debug; then echo "Checking Mail service to see if SMTP plaintext auth is supported..."; fi
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ (plain|login) ]]; then
        if $debug; then echo "  Found '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}' SMTP auth method which is plaintext!"; fi
        plaintext_auth_enabled=true
    fi
done <<< "$(serveradmin settings mail:postfix:smtpd_pw_server_security_options)"

# if plaintext auth is enabled, notify admins
if $plaintext_auth_enabled; then
    if $debug; then echo "Notifying admins via email that SMTP plaintext auth IS supported. That's bad!"; fi
    mail -s "Error on $host: SMTP plaintext auth is allowed! $date" $admin_emails <<-EOM
        ERROR on $host: SMTP plaintext auth appears to be allowed by the Mail service! This is a security risk and against PCI DSS compliance!

        Please resolve ASAP!
    EOM
else
    if $debug; then echo "Phew, SMTP plaintext auth doesn't appear to be supported. That's good."; fi
fi
```

Again, it's a *workaround* and I'd much prefer to programmatically disable SMTP plaintext auth.